# how to implement crosstab in query with multi join and subqueries ? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery, crosstab

How to apply crosstab in my case ..

I want to make the PRODUCT NAME as a columns so I can avoid duplicated records of **DC_Name,Call and Register Outlet**.

and after I did some research I found that CrossTab can give me what I want .. but I don't know how to implement it to my Query .. because the Example of the Tutorials was so simple and easy ..

can someone tell me how to implement it to my query ..

and here is my Query :

```
select
            dist.NM_DIST as DC_Name,
            call.Call,
            ro.RegisterOulet,
            c.NAMA_SGRUP as Product_Name,
            c.EffectiveCall
            ,f.OT as Out_Transaction
            ,c.EffectiveCall/f.ot as Ratio
            ,g.SBQ as Sales_by_qty
from assrkmd as a
inner join asscusext as ext on ext.KODE_CUS=a.KODE_CUS
inner join assdistributor as dist on dist.KD_DIST=ext.KD_DIST
inner join (
                select dis.KD_DIST,count(a.KODE_CUS ) as Call
                from assrkmd as a 
                inner join asscusext as cus on cus.KODE_CUS=a.KODE_CUS
                inner join assdistributor as dis on dis.KD_DIST=cus.KD_DIST
                where (a.TGL_RKM  between '20211101' and '20211130') and a.CHECK_OUT is not null 
                group by dis.KD_DIST
        ) as call on call.KD_DIST=dist.KD_DIST
inner join (
                select d.KD_DIST, d.NM_DIST, count(b.KODE_CUS) as RegisterOulet
                from assmds as a
                inner join asscus as b on a.KODE_SLS=b.KODE_SAL
                inner join asscusext as c on b.KODE_CUS=c.KODE_CUS
                inner join assdistributor as d on d.KD_DIST=c.KD_DIST
                group by d.KD_DIST, d.NM_DIST
        ) as RO on RO.KD_DIST=dist.KD_DIST
inner join (
            select a.KD_DIST, a.NM_DIST, a.KODE_SGRUP, a.NAMA_SGRUP, count(a.TGL_RKM) as EffectiveCall
            from ( 
                    select f.KD_DIST, f.NM_DIST, h.KODE_MDS, h.NAMA_MDS, e.KODE_CUS, g.NAMA_PT, d.KODE_SGRUP, d.NAMA_SGRUP, b.TGL_RKM
                    from assrkmdjuald as a
                    inner join assrkmdjualh as b on a.TGL_RKM=b.TGL_RKM and a.NO_NOTA=b.NO_NOTA
                    inner join asstok as c on a.KODE_BRG=c.KODE_BRG
                    inner join asssgrupbrg as d on c.KODE_SGRUP=d.KODE_SGRUP
                    inner join asscusext as e on e.KODE_CUS=b.KODE_CUS
                    inner join asscus as g on g.KODE_CUS=e.KODE_CUS
                    inner join assmds as h on h.KODE_SLS=g.KODE_SAL
                    inner join assdistributor as f on f.KD_DIST=e.KD_DIST
                    group by f.KD_DIST, f.NM_DIST, h.KODE_MDS, h.NAMA_MDS, e.KODE_CUS, g.NAMA_PT, d.KODE_SGRUP, d.NAMA_SGRUP, b.TGL_RKM
                ) as a
            where a.TGL_RKM between '20211101' and '20211130'
            group by a.KD_DIST, a.NM_DIST, a.KODE_SGRUP, a.NAMA_SGRUP
        ) as c on c.KD_DIST=ro.KD_DIST
left join (
                select ext.KD_DIST,b.KODE_SGRUP, count(b.KODE_CUS) as OT
                from asscusext as ext 
                inner join (
                                select a.KD_DIST,a.KODE_CUS,d.KODE_SGRUP
                                from asscusext as a
                                inner join assrkmd as kmd on kmd.kode_cus=a.kode_cus
                                inner join assrkmdjuald as b on b.KODE_CUS=a.KODE_CUS
                                left join asstok as c on c.KODE_BRG=b.KODE_BRG
                                inner join asssgrupbrg as d on d.KODE_SGRUP=c.KODE_SGRUP
                                where (kmd.TGL_RKM  between '20211101' and '20211130') and kmd.CHECK_OUT is not null 
                                group by a.KD_DIST,a.KODE_CUS,d.KODE_SGRUP
                        ) as b on b.KODE_CUS=ext.KODE_CUS
                group by ext.KD_DIST,b.KODE_SGRUP
        ) as f on f.KODE_SGRUP=c.KODE_SGRUP and f.KD_DIST=c.KD_DIST
left join (
                select  c.KODE_SGRUP,SUM(a.JUM_KARTON*b.FRACT+a.JUM_SATUAN)as SBQ
                from assrkmdjuald as a
                left join (select kode_brg,KODE_SGRUP,fract from asstok) as b on b.KODE_BRG=a.KODE_BRG
                inner join asssgrupbrg as c on c.KODE_SGRUP=b.KODE_SGRUP
                inner join asscusext as ext on ext.KODE_CUS=a.KODE_CUS
                inner join assdistributor as dist on dist.KD_DIST=ext.KD_DIST
                where (a.TGL_RKM  between '20211101' and '20211130')
                group by c.KODE_SGRUP
        ) as g on g.KODE_SGRUP=f.KODE_SGRUP
where (a.TGL_RKM  between '20211101' and '20211130')
group by call.Call,ro.RegisterOulet,ext.KD_DIST,dist.NM_DIST,g.SBQ,c.NAMA_SGRUP,f.ot,c.EffectiveCall
order by ext.kd_dist desc
```

above query gaves me this Result :

| DC_Name | Call | RegisterOutlet | Product Name | EffectiveCall | Transaction | Ratio | sales by qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DC CILACAP | 888 | 605 | Single Sosis | 848 | 523 | 1 | 329859 |
| DC CILACAP | 888 | 605 | Drink 240 ML | 217 | 523 | 0 | 18298 |
| DC CIANJUR | 546 | 354 | Single Sosis | 504 | 293 | 1 | 329859 |
| DC CIANJUR | 546 | 354 | Drink 240 ML | 42 | 125 | 0 | 16884 |

that's not wanted result ..

and the result that i want it is like this (Avoid the Colspan and Rowspan of Header) :

```
|     -    |  -  |      -       |     Effective Call      |     transaction         |          Ratio          |     Sales By Qty        |
|DC_Name   | Call|RegisterOutlet|Single Sosis|Drink 240 ML|Single Sosis|Drink 240 ML|Single Sosis|Drink 240 ML|Single Sosis|Drink 240 ML|
|DC CILACAP| 888 |     605      |   848      |    217     |    523     |    523     |      1     |      0      |   329859   |   18298    |
|DC CIANJUR| 546 |     354      |   504      |     42     |     293    |    125     |      1     |      0      |   329859   |   16884    |
```

Please Help me out to get my desire Table (dynamic or non-dynamic its ok for me )  or maybe give me some tips and step of crossTab for query with multi join so i can follow it. **Product Name can be More than2 or Less than 2 **.

Comment: You need to use a PIVOT or a CASE to do so. If there is only 2 different product names, CASE will be appropiate. As an example to transforme Effective Call in two columns : SUM(CASE Product Name WHEN 'Single Sosis' THEN EffectiveCall ELSE 0 END) AS "Effective Call : Single Sosis". Then you have to group by all other columns...

Comment: but the first headers (EffectiveCall-transaction-etc..)  it not really important but i wrote it in the question di make it clear  .. i just wanna make the Product name as a header .. .. so i'm gonna try Sum(CASE  WHEN Product Name='Single Sosis' THEN EffectiveCall ELSE 0 END) as Single Sosis . right ?

Comment: yes of course you can !

Answer (score 3):

Here is your query rewrite witc much more clearer CTE (Common Table Expression) :

```
WITH
T_CALL AS
(
   select dis.KD_DIST, count(a.KODE_CUS ) as Call
   from   assrkmd as a 
          inner join asscusext as cus 
             on cus.KODE_CUS=a.KODE_CUS
          inner join assdistributor as dis 
             on dis.KD_DIST=cus.KD_DIST
   where  a.TGL_RKM  between '20211101' and '20211130' 
          and a.CHECK_OUT is not null 
   group by dis.KD_DIST
),
T_RO AS
(
   select d.KD_DIST, d.NM_DIST, count(b.KODE_CUS) as RegisterOulet
   from   assmds as a
          inner join asscus as b 
             on a.KODE_SLS=b.KODE_SAL
          inner join asscusext as c 
             on b.KODE_CUS=c.KODE_CUS
          inner join assdistributor as d 
          on d.KD_DIST=c.KD_DIST
   group  by d.KD_DIST, d.NM_DIST
),
T_A AS
(
   select f.KD_DIST, f.NM_DIST, h.KODE_MDS, h.NAMA_MDS, 
          e.KODE_CUS, g.NAMA_PT, d.KODE_SGRUP, d.NAMA_SGRUP, b.TGL_RKM
   from   assrkmdjuald as a
          inner join assrkmdjualh as b 
             on a.TGL_RKM=b.TGL_RKM and a.NO_NOTA=b.NO_NOTA
          inner join asstok as c 
             on a.KODE_BRG=c.KODE_BRG
          inner join asssgrupbrg as d 
             on c.KODE_SGRUP=d.KODE_SGRUP
          inner join asscusext as e 
             on e.KODE_CUS=b.KODE_CUS
          inner join asscus as g 
             on g.KODE_CUS=e.KODE_CUS
          inner join assmds as h 
             on h.KODE_SLS=g.KODE_SAL
          inner join assdistributor as f 
             on f.KD_DIST=e.KD_DIST
   group  by f.KD_DIST, f.NM_DIST, h.KODE_MDS, h.NAMA_MDS, 
          e.KODE_CUS, g.NAMA_PT, d.KODE_SGRUP, d.NAMA_SGRUP, b.TGL_RKM
),
T_C AS
(
   select a.KD_DIST, a.NM_DIST, a.KODE_SGRUP, a.NAMA_SGRUP, 
          count(a.TGL_RKM) as EffectiveCall
   from   T_A as a
   where  a.TGL_RKM between '20211101' and '20211130'
   group  by a.KD_DIST, a.NM_DIST, a.KODE_SGRUP, a.NAMA_SGRUP
),
T_B AS
(
   select a.KD_DIST,a.KODE_CUS,d.KODE_SGRUP
   from   asscusext as a
          inner join assrkmd as kmd 
             on kmd.kode_cus=a.kode_cus
          inner join assrkmdjuald as b 
             on b.KODE_CUS=a.KODE_CUS
          left join asstok as c 
             on c.KODE_BRG=b.KODE_BRG
          inner join asssgrupbrg as d 
             on d.KODE_SGRUP=c.KODE_SGRUP
   where  kmd.TGL_RKM  between '20211101' and '20211130' 
          and kmd.CHECK_OUT is not null 
   group  by a.KD_DIST,a.KODE_CUS,d.KODE_SGRUP
),
T_F AS
(
   select ext.KD_DIST, b.KODE_SGRUP, count(b.KODE_CUS) as OT
   from   asscusext as ext 
          inner join T_B as b 
             on b.KODE_CUS=ext.KODE_CUS
   group  by ext.KD_DIST,b.KODE_SGRUP
),
T_BB AS
(  
   select kode_brg, KODE_SGRUP, fract 
   from   asstok
),
T_G AS
(
   select c.KODE_SGRUP, SUM(a.JUM_KARTON * b.FRACT + a.JUM_SATUAN) as SBQ
   from   assrkmdjuald as a
          left join T_BB as b 
             on b.KODE_BRG=a.KODE_BRG
          inner join asssgrupbrg as c 
             on c.KODE_SGRUP=b.KODE_SGRUP
          inner join asscusext as ext 
             on ext.KODE_CUS=a.KODE_CUS
          inner join assdistributor as dist 
             on dist.KD_DIST=ext.KD_DIST
   where  a.TGL_RKM  between '20211101' and '20211130'
   group  by c.KODE_SGRUP
)
select dist.NM_DIST as DC_Name,
       call.Call,
       ro.RegisterOulet,
       c.NAMA_SGRUP as Product_Name,
       c.EffectiveCall,
       f.OT as Out_Transaction,
       c.EffectiveCall/f.ot as Ratio,
       g.SBQ as Sales_by_qty
from   assrkmd as a
       inner join asscusext as ext 
          on ext.KODE_CUS=a.KODE_CUS
       inner join assdistributor as dist 
          on dist.KD_DIST=ext.KD_DIST
       inner join T_CALL as call 
          on call.KD_DIST=dist.KD_DIST
       inner join T_RO as RO 
          on RO.KD_DIST=dist.KD_DIST
       inner join T_C as c 
          on c.KD_DIST=ro.KD_DIST
       left join T_F as f 
          on f.KODE_SGRUP=c.KODE_SGRUP and f.KD_DIST=c.KD_DIST
       left join T_G as g 
          on g.KODE_SGRUP=f.KODE_SGRUP
where  a.TGL_RKM  between '20211101' and '20211130'
group  by call.Call, ro.RegisterOulet, ext.KD_DIST, dist.NM_DIST,
       g.SBQ,c.NAMA_SGRUP,f.ot,c.EffectiveCall
order  by ext.kd_dist desc;
```

Now the only thing you have to do is to add a new CTE which integrates the four CASE statement as given above

Comment: do u  mean like this ? Sum(CASE WHEN c.NAMA_SGRUP='Kanzler Singles Sosis' THEN c.EffectiveCall  ELSE '' END) as Kanzler_Single_Sosis ? .. its work but why the result is different ?